# How to create a parallax effect in pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a parallax effect to my home page.

Currently, the background image is fixed, but this is not the effect I'm looking for.

I want the background to be slower than my page.

As in this example :

https://codepen.io/RenanB/pen/GZeBNg

I managed to do this in javascript but I have a lot of problems with Drupal 8.

So I want to have a parallax effect in pure CSS.

I tried to follow this tutorial that is already two years old, but I have not managed to adapt my code :

http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

Here is the style sheet of my homepage :

```
/*-------------------------------------------*
/* Page accueil
/*-------------------------------------------*/

.path-frontpage .main-container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.path-frontpage .main-container .row {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.path-frontpage .main-container .row .col-sm-12 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

#block-parallax1 {
    background-image: url("/themes/contrib/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/images/parallax-1.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 10em 0em 10em 0em;
    background-color: #3b842d;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#block-parallax2 {
    background-image: url("/themes/contrib/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/images/parallax-2.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 10em 0em 10em 0em;
    background-color: #3b842d;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#block-parallax3  {
    background-image: url("/themes/contrib/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/images/parallax-3.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 10em 0em 10em 0em;
    background-color: #3b842d;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#block-parallax4 {
    background-image: url("/themes/contrib/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/images/parallax-4.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 10em 0em 10em 0em;
    background-color: #3b842d;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#block-parallax5 {
    background-image: url("/themes/contrib/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/images/parallax-5.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 10em 0em 10em 0em;
    background-color: #3b842d;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#block-section1,
#block-section2,
#block-section3,
#block-section4,
#block-section5 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2em;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #3b842d;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#block-parallax1 .field--name-body,
#block-parallax2 .field--name-body,
#block-parallax3 .field--name-body,
#block-parallax4 .field--name-body,
#block-parallax5 .field--name-body {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38823529411764707);
}

#block-parallax1 h2,
#block-parallax2 h2,
#block-parallax3 h2,
#block-parallax4 h2,
#block-parallax5 h2,
#block-section1 h2,
#block-section2 h2,
#block-section3 h2,
#block-section4 h2,
#block-section5 h2 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#block-parallax1 p,
#block-parallax2 p,
#block-parallax3 p,
#block-parallax4 p,
#block-parallax5 p {
    font-size: 16px;
}

#block-section1 p,
#block-section2 p,
#block-section3 p,
#block-section4 p,
#block-section5 p {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

[image]

I'm looking for the parallax effect of Slide 3:

https://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/JycFw?editors=1100

Comment: can you add your rendered html code and css to jsfiddle.net? so that its easier to test

Comment: @Znaneswar This is the first time I use this site. I hope it's ok
 https://jsfiddle.net/pdmv8jkr/3/

Comment: @user2951257 I formulated my question here

Comment: I followed several tutorials but I did not succeed

Answer (score 1):

i hope this code helps for you

https://jsfiddle.net/LmjeLbmk/20/

```css
.parallax {
    font-size: 200%;
}
.parallax {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-perspective: 1px;
    perspective: 1px;
}
.parallax__layer {
    padding: 100vh 0;
}

.parallax__layer--back {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
     transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}
.parallax__layer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
      <div class="title">This is the background</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
      <div class="title">This is the foreground</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LmjeLbmk/20/

as per your comment, to hide scrollbar try this code

```
.parallax1::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 0px;
background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you how to put a background in full screen? Can you give me an example with this?
 https://pixabay.com/fr/no%C3%ABl-cadeaux-geschenksack-sac-2947257/

Comment: updated code to disable scrollbar and use updated version with ` transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);` for full page background image check fiddle i added in post

Comment: I updated my style sheet but still have the same problem. I do not know what's wrong. Can you look at the homepage of my site?

Comment: I watched the parallax effect and it does not match what I'm looking for. I would like only the bottom to move at a different speed while the page is scrolling. Like here
 https://codepen.io/RenanB/pen/GZeBNg

Comment: I think with pure css its very hard/not possible to create same exact result as codepen.

Comment: Here we succeed with group 2. That's exactly what I want to do. http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/demo3-webkit-overflow-fix/