# How do I make one div scroll slower or faster than other items on the page, using pure CSS or CSS/JS (without JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

All I want is to do is to make one element on the page (a div is easiest) scroll slower or faster than the other items on the page.  For example, when scrolling, this particular div will move at 50% or 200% of the speed of the other items, etc.

It seems like such a simple, straightforward thing, but I can't find any examples of this.  Also, I don't want to use JQuery, someone else's sketchy / overly complicated 3rd party plugin, etc.  Just simple, clean, CSS and JS.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/36dp03ur/ ???

Comment: Kind of, except that the slower or faster scroll rate should remain a constant slow or faster speed, and it also works with the scroll bar...

Comment: Im not sure if you can do this to be honest as the Browser defaults the Scroll speed :/ maybe someone can enlighten me

Comment: So are you looking for the speed to change only when scrolling that element, or do you want that part to move slower than the rest of the page as it all scrolls together?

Comment: Not sure if I can think/find a way of doing that (at least right now). You might have to write JS for this scenario your self. But if you can use jQuery or JS plugins then here are some options available: https://github.com/zengabor/zenscroll (JS Plugin) or https://github.com/nathco/jQuery.scrollSpeed (requires jQuery). Sorry if this is not suitable for your needs.

Comment: "do you want that part to move slower than the rest of the page as it all scrolls together"

Yep, this is what I'm looking for.  Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: @escapetomars I am thinking that this should be achievable with CSS and JS only using a floating element and x,y positions as the basis for the slow scrolling element. You have piqued my curiosity here, I am going to attempt to figure it out. Bear with me a while

Comment: _"but I can't find any examples of this"_ there are hundreds of similar questions just on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Turnip So you say, but in the end I found that they are either 
A) not answered and down-voted into oblivion or 
B) answered with overly complicated JQuery or plugins designed to do something far more complex

Comment: @Ajaypayne cool, thanks, I'll check back in a little while then :)

Comment: First result in Google for "stack overflow css parallax": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406292/how-to-create-a-parallax-effect-in-pure-css

Comment: @Turnip This link doesn't answer my question.  I'm looking for an object sitting on top of everything else that simply scrolls slower or faster than the rest of the page.  I'm not looking for a parallax background.

Comment: Did you look at the answer in that thread? It does exactly as you just described.

Comment: No, it definitely does not.  I figured out a way to do this properly for myself, you can see below. That is what I wanted. Super simple, totally beyond the ability of most people to figure out, for some inexplicable reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have managed to come up with this which is not too complex, however, it does scroll relative to the users scroll speed, but does work with scroll wheel, scrollbars, and keyboard.

It also scrolls up and down.

You can change the speed to suit your needs, but 10 worked for keeping it pretty much in view all the way down for my scroll speed, but left it behind when faster or using Page Down.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function DomContentLoaded(){
  //Get the element you want to slow down;
  var slowDiv = document.getElementById('slowDiv');
  //Set its style.top to be the offsetTop so if style.top is not set, it will still work.
  slowDiv.style.top = slowDiv.offsetTop + 'px';
  //set the last scrollTop to use for direction
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  //Get the element you are scrolling against
  var relativeSpeedDiv = document.getElementById('main');


  var moveLittle = function MoveLittle(speed, scrollY) {
    //Get the current top of the slow element
    var topVal = parseInt(slowDiv.style.top);
    //Check scroll direction
    if (isScrollingDown(scrollY)) {
      topVal = topVal + speed;
    } else {
      topVal = topVal - speed;
    }
    //Set new top of slow element
    slowDiv.style.top = topVal + 'px';
  };

  var isScrollingDown = function IsScrollingDown(scrollY) {
    var retVal = false;
    if (scrollY > lastScrollTop) {
      retVal = true;
    }
    lastScrollTop = scrollY;
    return retVal;
  };

  window.onscroll = function WindowScroll() {
    //Send speed and current scroll Y
    moveLittle(10, this.scrollY);
  }

});
```

```css
.biggestBig {
    margin: auto;
    align-self: center;
    width: 90%;
    min-height: 9999em;
}

.faded {
    background: linear-gradient(gray, black);
}

.slow {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    background-color: #ee9b0b;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv" class="biggestBig faded">
    <div id="slowDiv" class="slow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Ok, so thanks @ajaypane for the answer, but I actually figured out an even simpler way of doing this.  I can't believe that nobody has done this - it's far less complicated than everything else I've seen.

JS

```
function parallax() {
    var s = document.getElementById("floater");
  var yPos = 0 - window.pageYOffset/5;  
  s.style.top = 50 + yPos + "%"; }

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    parallax(); 
});
```

CSS

```
.section { position: relative; width: 100vw; height: 15vw; }
.object-in-3d { 
  margin-left: 45vw;
  width: 10vw; 
  height: 10vw; 
  background-color: #41ebf4; }

.float-center { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 50%; }

#red { background-color: #f44141; }
#yellow { background-color: #f48342; }
#green { background-color: #f4dc41; }

#floater {}
```

HTML

```
<div class="section" id="red">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="section" id="yellow">
  <div class="object-in-3d float-center" id="floater">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div class="section" id="green">&nbsp;</div>
```

It's in codepen, here:

https://codepen.io/escapetomars/pen/EeLmpp